# Does $x^x=y^y\iff x=y$, given $x,y\in\Bbb R$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am curious whether the following is true:

> Does $x^x=y^y\iff x=y$, given $x,y\in\Bbb R$?

I can see how $x=y\implies x^x=y^y$. We can raise one side of the equation by $x$ and another by $y$ and still maintain equality because $x=y$.

But the question becomes less clear when going the other way($x^x=y^y\implies x=y$). It is not intuitive whether or not this is true, and I can't seem to see any counterexample to this. I tried to take the $\ln$ of both sides to get $x\ln x=y\ln y$, and maybe do $e$ to the power of both sides(to get rid of $\ln$), but I'm not too sure if I'm on the right track. Also, $\ln$ is only valid for $x,y>0$ so it doesn't even cover all the possibilities. This question might be trivial, but I don't really see how to continue from here. Any thoughts?

Comment: Keep in mind, if you take $e$ to the power of both sides, you end up exactly where you started because you've essentially written $f(f^{-1}(x))$.

Comment: Have you seen a graph of $x^x$?  In particular, look at the range $(0,1)$.  Also, if you know how, differentiate $x^x$.

Comment: $x^x$ has a minimum somewhere in $(0,1)$ so it cannot be injective on all $\mathbb R$. This is true for $x\ge 1$ easily, but you can calculate the derivative to find the exact interval.

Comment: What is $x^x$ if $x=-1.5$?

Comment: @zwim So what you are saying is that this is not true for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$, but only true on a certain interval?

Comment: A striclty monotonic function is always injective, so find the different intervals where $x^x$ is monotonic (stricly $\nearrow$ or $\searrow$).

Comment: It’s true on any intreval that $f$ can be considered one to one @AidenChow. By definition, $f(x)=f(y) \iff x=y$ means that $f$ is one to one. Your function is not one to one on it’s entire domain. For instance, take $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: @StephenGoree My original intention was to apply lambert w function after I got $xe^x=ye^y$, but I wasn't sure whether I did a mistake somewhere or whether I was on the right track.

Comment: @AidenChow This is quite an old post now, but I see that you use ``\Longleftrightarrow`` rather than ``\iff`` (short for 'if and only if') to produce the $\iff$ symbol. The latter is a lot shorter to type! Also, feel free to accept one of the answers as you see fit. I used calculus in my answer—if you haven't learn it before, I can adapt my answer so that it makes more sense to you.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the mathjax suggestion! I am in fact only in the ninth grade so I'm only in the precalculus/trigonometry stage, so I don't understand your answer that well. But I got the idea of the turning point, so you can keep that part in.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the graph of $f(x)=x^x$:
[image: Graph of x^x]

This graph appears to have a turning point somewhere around $x=0.5$, and we can use calculus to find out exactly when this is true. If $z=x^x$, then $\ln z = \ln x^x=x\ln x$. If we differentiate both sides of this equation, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z}\frac{dz}{dx}&=\ln x + x\cdot\frac{1}{x}=\ln x + 1 \\[6pt]
\frac{dz}{dx}&=z(\ln x + 1)
\end{align}
To find the turning point set $\frac{dz}{dx}$ equal to $0$. It turns out that the graph has a turning point when $x=1/e$. Of course, in this case, what matters is not when the graph has a turning point, but the fact that it *does* have one. This means that $f$ is not one-to-one, i.e. there may be multiple $x$ that correspond to the same output. Can you see where this is going?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to there being a range of real solutions for $x^x=y^y, x\not=y$, there are also infinitely many solutions where both $x$ and $y$ are rational.

For any positive whole number $n$, render

$x=(n/(n+1))^n, y=(n/(n+1))^{n+1}<x; x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$

Then

$y^y=\left(\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\right)^{\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}$

$=\left(\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\right)^{\left(\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\right)}$

$=\left(\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^{(n+1)\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)}\right)^{\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^n}$

$=\left(\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\right)^{\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^n}=x^x$

With $y<x,x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have an all-rational solution for each positive whole number $n$.  Combined with the abalysidls by Joe this result implies more precisely $y<e<x$.

Comment: I don't think you typed your equations properly. It isn't showing up for me.

Comment: Now I am in trouble with parentheses size.  Hard for me to figure out.  Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend using `\left` and `\right` to fix this problem

Comment: Failed.  When I replace the outer ( with left and the outer ) with \right the top equation goes bad.  What did I miss/how to solve?

Comment: I have submitted an edit that may have solved your issue. Please check it out.

Comment: @aiden chow approved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We have $x \log(x) = y \log(y)$. Because we are seeking for solutions with $x\ne y$ and the equation is symmetrix, assume WLOG that $y>x$. Then let $y= a x$ for some $a>1$. Then

$$\begin{align}
 x \log(x) &= ax \log(x) + ax \log(a)\\
 x\log (x) (1-a) &= ax \log(a) \\
x  &=  a^{a/(1-a)} 
\end{align}
$$

For $a\to 1$ this tends to $x_0 = 1/e$.
Then we have infinite pair of solutions with $x \in (0, 1/e)$  and $y \in (1/e, 1)$

Some values

```
a        x        y
1.01   0.36605   0.36971
2      1/4       1/2
5      0.13375   0.66874
```